# Prevent unwanted animations on subviews when animating constraints

Tags: ios, animation, constraints

Usually you get unwanted animations on UITableViewCells when animating the height of the UITableView.  The new cells that get reused come in and have weird unwanted animations on the subviews that get laid out.  This is usually visible when the table expands.

The animations usually look like the objects pop in from a corner since it animates the width and height of the subviews for some reason from 0 to the size they're supposed to be.

This can sort of be solved by overriding in the cell's layoutSubviews method.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [super layoutSubviews];
    }];
}
```

But this still doesn't prevent the contained subviews from doing unwanted animations.  It also doesn't prevent unwanted animations when you add things to contentView of a cell.  You basically have to override the layoutSubviews methods of every single subview you have if it too has subviews.

This isn't always possible, like in the case of contentView.  I can't override the contentView class and tell it to lay out its subviews without animations.  This is also a very cumbersome fix since I need to add this to every single UIView object that I am able to override.

I still haven't found the answer that fixes this once and for all.  How to just animate a constraint on something but prevent strange unwanted animations on its subviews.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered a similar problem in a UICollectionView and was able to fix it in its delegate:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // setup your cell
    // ...

    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This does help.

Comment: It works well. But if the cell contains accessory checkmark, the checkmark will be shown animated from left. I tried to mv this code snippet to `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, solved my case. Hope it helps for others.

Answer (score 0):

The other responses are right, but you have to do it on all view hierarchy. Add this extension method and call it on the ** subview** that doesn't need to animate.

```
public func commitSuperviewsLayout() {
    var processedSuperview = superview

    while processedSuperview != nil {
        processedSuperview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        processedSuperview = processedSuperview?.superview
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, if you put the `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` before `UIView.animate`, it doesn't work. If you put it after, it works! Sequence matters :D

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //        print("I am being edited")
    
    if self.searchCancelButton.isHidden {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.searchCancelButton.isHidden.toggle()
            self.topStack.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        self.state = .searchFoodView
        refreshEmptySearchFoodView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, what I do if I only want to animate certain things and not others is make sure all the constraints that shouldn't animate are set, and after that call

```
[view layoutIfNeeded]
```

on the parent view of the views impacted by those constraints.

Finally I set the constants on the constraints I want to animate and call

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{ [view layoutIfNeeded];}];
```

Comment: But sometimes I just need to change the height of a tableView.  There is one constraint I'm setting.

The rest animate beyond my control.

Comment: What @iseletsky is referring to, is the animations that the system does when you expand a view and originally had a 0 height or 0 width, it does not only animates the change in the side you are expanding, it also animates a change in the other side, or if you instantiate a nib, it animates the readjustments from the original size to the new size.